# Доступ к свойству класса только на чтение C#

Tags: c#, классы

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы

```
        public class MyNum
        {
            public string val;
            public MyNum(string arg1)
            {
                val = arg1;
            }

        }
MyNum temp11;
```

И чтобы при попытке

```
temp11.val="dsdfSDf";
```

Возникала ошибка. И можно было только конструктором задать значение val?
А вот такое

```
string a= temp11.val;
```

Работало. То есть получить свойство val можно было бы!!! Наверняка есть функция "закрывающая" доступ туда, например, что-то а-ля Set_Protected_to(val) внутри конструктора?

(как я понимаю protected не подходит. Свойство val вообще не доступно в коде?)

Comment: `Свойство val` - наведите на `val` и посмотрите, что пишет вам студия. А пишет она то, что это поле. Свойствами в C# называют то, что имеет `get` и `set`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, val и получилось у меня свойством. В ответе на вопрос как раз get и set используются для "свойства". Так что это свойство. Верно?

Comment: Я вам не про ответ говорю, а про ваш код, который в вопросе. Вы `public string val;` называете "свойством", что совершенно не [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw6PJ.png). В ответе же вам из `val` сделали свойство, да - `public string val { get; private set; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyNum
{
    public string val { get; private set; }
    public MyNum(string arg1)
    {
        val = arg1;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyNum
{
    private string _val;
    public string val { get { return _val; } }
    public MyNum(string arg1)
    {
        _val = arg1;
    }
}
```

Comment: уже можно без приватной переменной